# MySQL counting number of groups

Tags: mysql

I have a rather complex statement that I'm trying to write. I'm not sure how to do it though, or even if it's possible.

I have a logging system that scans a server and catalogs every user that's online at that given moment. Here is how my table looks like:

```
-----------------
|    ab_logs    |
-----------------
|      id       |
|    scan_id    |
|  found_user   |
-----------------
```

`id` is an autoincrementing primary key. Has no real value other than that.

`scan_id` is an integer that is incremented after each successful scan of all users. It so I can separate results from different scans.

`found_user`. Stores which user was found online during the scan.

The above will generate a table that could look like this:

```
id  |  scan_id  | found_user
----------------------------
1   |     1     |   Nick
2   |     2     |   Nick
3   |     2     |   John
4   |     3     |   John
```

So on the first scan the system found only Nick online. On the 2nd it found both Nick and John. On the 3rd only John was still online.

I know I can get the number of users that were online during a given scan by the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ab_logs WHERE scan_id = $scan_id
```

---

My problem is that I want to get the above **for all** scans in **one result**. Is this possible without looping the above query X times?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ab_logs GROUP BY scan_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ab_logs GROUP BY scan_id
```

Comment: Cheers! I thought `GROUP BY` only affects how data is output and not the actual calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ab_logs GROUP BY scan_id
```

Comment: Please upvote answers already posted, rather than simply duplicating them.

Comment: @BenM i know this answer so i answered it ok i will take care that :)